# How to conver this comma and delimiter seperated string into organized array in PHP?

Tags: php

I am looking for a way to convert this string:

```
term:entertainment,taxonomy:category,term:lifestyle,taxonomy:category
```

Into this PHP array (organized, no duplicate taxonomy)

```
Array ( [category] => entertainment,lifestyle )
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$splitted = explode(",", $string);
for ($i = 0; $i < count($splitted); $i+=2) {
    $result = explode(":",$splitted[$i])[1]; // (PHP 5.4 syntax)
    $key = explode(":",$splitted[$i+1])[1];
    if (isset($array[$key]))
        $array[$key] .= ",$result";
    else
        $array[$key] = $result;
}
```

It first splits by comma, then adds the data to an array splitting by semicolon.

(When your string has always the same form, this is enough.)